# Stop top-fixed element when reach div

Tags: html

I have a page with 2 navbars.
The first one is fixed at the top of the page.
The second, in the middle of the page, become "top-sticky" when I scroll.

I would like to stop the 1st navbar just before reaching the 2nd.
So that when you scroll after the 2nd navbar, only this one is visible, the 1st stays upper/ disappear.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helloducoux/jegqyrb1/1/)

My html :

```
<body>
<div id="page"> 
  <div class="fullscreen">
    <h1>Zone fullscreen</h1>
    </div>
  <header class="navbar1">
    <p>Navbar 1 : I am fixed but I want to stop just before Navbar2 !</p>
  </header> 
  <div id="content">
    <div class="navbar2">
     <p>Navbar 2 : I become sticky on scroll</p>
    </div><!--/navbarLoc-->
  <div class="main-content">
    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
  </div><!--/content -->
</div><!--/page-->
</body>
```

CSS :

```
* {padding:0; margin:0;}
html, body, #page {height:100%;}

.fullscreen {height: 100%;background: red;position:relative; z-index:5;}
.fullscreen h1 {padding-top:180px;text-align:center;}

.navbar1 {position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; top:10px;background:yellow;padding:5px;z-index:15;}
.navbar2 {background:green;padding:5px;z-index:20;}

.main-content {padding:10px;position:relative; z-index:10;}
.main-content p {font-size:50px;}
```

And JS :

This is for making Navbar2 sticky :

```
$(".navbar2").stick_in_parent({offset_top:40});
```

And I found this piece of code, to make the navbar1 absolute when reach Navbar2, doesnt work :

```
function checkOffset() {
    if($('.navbar1').offset().top + $('.navbar1').height() >=     $('.navbar2').offset().top - 10)
        $('.navbar1').css('position', 'absolute');
    if($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight <    $('.navbar2').offset().top)
    $('.navbar1').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
    $('.navbar1').text($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight);
}
$(document).scroll(function() {
    checkOffset();
});
```

And maybe the best solution would be to add/remove a class instead of directly applying CSS ?

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance for your reply !

Comment: Do you want navbar1 to be fixed till the user scroll to navbar2, then the navbar2 will be the fixed one? Right @imudo

Comment: Yes that's exactly that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, First I've some notes that I'd like to share with you

1. I'm not sure why you're using header for navbar1, so I just updated it to be div
2. You're using too much useless CSS, no need to all these display, position and z-index attributes, so I removed unnecessary styles

Please check the code below, it's supposed to to do what you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar1").addClass("fixedbar");
  $(".navbar2").removeClass("fixedbar");
  
  var bar2pos=$('.navbar2').offset().top - $('.navbar2').outerHeight();
  
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    
    if($(this).scrollTop()>= bar2pos && !$(".navbar2").hasClass("fixedbar")){
       $(".navbar1").removeClass("fixedbar");
       $(".navbar2").addClass("fixedbar");
    }
    
    if($(this).scrollTop()<=bar2pos && $(".navbar2").hasClass("fixedbar")){
        $(".navbar1").addClass("fixedbar");
        $(".navbar2").removeClass("fixedbar");
    }
  });
  
});
```

```css
    * {padding:0; margin:0;}
html, body, #page {height:100%;}

.fullscreen {background: red;}
.fullscreen h1 {padding-top:180px;text-align:center;}

.navbar1 {background:yellow; padding:5px; width:100%;}
.navbar2 {background:green; padding:5px; width:100%;}

.main-content {padding:10px;}
.main-content p {font-size:50px;}

.fixedbar
{
   position: fixed;
   left: 0px;
   top : 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="page"> 
  <div class="navbar1">
    <p>Navbar 1 : I am fixed but I want to stop just before Navbar2 !</p>
  </div> 
  <div class="fullscreen">
    <h1>Zone fullscreen</h1>
 </div>
  
  <div class="navbar2">
     <p>Navbar 2 : I become sticky on scroll</p>
 </div><!--/navbarLoc-->
  <div id="content">
    
  <div class="main-content">
    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
  </div><!--/content -->
</div><!--/page-->
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is very nice.

Question : is it possible to configure the distance (before or after?) the anchor point ?
I mean : now the class fixedbar is added/removed when the two navbars touch each other.
Could we say for example : "add/remove fixedbar 10 px before navbar1 touch navbar2" ?

Comment: @imudo, yes you can easily manipulate the distance before turning navbar2 to fixedbar, this line 
var bar2pos=$('.navbar2').offset().top - $('.navbar2').outerHeight();
can be updated to be 
var bar2pos=$('.navbar2').offset().top - $('.navbar2').outerHeight()-10;
This will change navbar2 to fixed bar when navbar1 is 10px before the start of navbar2